# Map issues when testing in IOS 8

Tags: google-maps, maps, ios8, mapbox

I have an application that uses MapBox's API to stylize the underlying map which uses Google Places. This all worked perfectly fine when running in IOS 7+, but when I try testing this in IOS 8, it immediately crashes with the following error message:

Terminating app due to uncaught exception `NSInternalInconsistencyException`, reason: 'The layout constraints still need update after sending -updateConstraints to MapView at {0,0}-{320x444}.
RMMapView or one of its superclasses may have overridden -updateConstraints without calling super. Or, something may have dirtied layout constraints in the middle of updating them.  Both are programming errors.'

I have been looking around the Web and Stack for a while but have been unable to find anything helpful unfortunately. Any suggestions?

Comment: I followed up on this in Mapbox support, but I'm not seeing this in iOS 8 on sim or device. Can you share some of the map init code that you are using?

Comment: Same problem for me. Do you have any updates since you posted this question ?

Comment: Hi incanus, sorry for the late reply thank you for getting back to me. We are trying to resolve this right now, to be sure that this is a MapBox issue and not something on our end. @Lionel - nothing useful yet but will keep you all posted!

Comment: @trdavidson : I deleted all Mapbox framework / headers / lib from my project and reinstalled the latest (1.4.1) mapbox static library (libMapbox.a) and the Headers, and everything was ok after that without changing a line of my code.

Comment: @LionelTressens Awesome!! Yes worked for me as well - glad this got resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deleted all Mapbox framework / headers / lib from my project and reinstalled the latest (1.4.1) mapbox static library (libMapbox.a) and the Headers, and everything was ok after that without changing a line of my code.